# How to change file input language

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've got this form with the code:

```
<form id="file-form" method="POST">
<input type="file" 
  onchange="openFile(event)" id="file-select">
 <img id="output">
 </form>
```

using html5 and when i use this function it automatically calls the english version of text in mobile iOS phone:

[image]

Now what i'm wondering is, does anyone know how to change the language of when calling for file input?

Any help or input highly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: I believe it's down to the locale setting of the browser/device

Comment: Oh okay, so maybe this is something i cant do anything about

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This comes from the users browser/OS and you can't change it.